# Is it possible to always show the address bar in Internet Explorer 10 Metro?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10, phishing

I'm setting up Windows 8 for a friend of mine, and I'm trying to ensure that they have a way to avoid going to phishing websites. When educating my friends about spoofed/phishing email I always advised them to keep an eye out for bad URLs.

With Internet Explorer 10 Metro the address bar is hidden and the user has to right click (or go to the bottom of the screen) to make it visible. I see this a very large potential security issue if, for example, they go to a fake bank website that attempts to steal their username and passwords. Personally, I love the [Modern UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29) experience, but is my only solution here to use an alternative browser or force Internet Explorer 10 in desktop mode here?

Comment: Can't you press something like CTRL+L to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At current there is no supported method for forcing the address bar to stay open in Internet Explorer 10. There may be a fix/hack in future updates, but I have not seen any so far.

My workaround is to use the Metro version of [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome). That task bar is always displayed, including any phishing warnings.

To install it, just install Chrome in the same way as Windows 7, then set it as the default browser. It will switch to Modern UI mode automatically.